# Split a string at & but not &&

Tags: php, preg-split

I have a URI that contains both `&` and `&&` and I need to split it into an array only at the single `&` delimiter, e.g. `query1=X&query2=A&&B&query3=Y`

should print out

```
array(
0   =>  query1=X
1   =>  query2=A&&B
2   =>  query3=Y
)
```

I know I can use `preg_split` but can't figure out the regex. Could someone help?

Comment: `preg_split("/&&/", text)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with `preg_match_all` *(all that isn't an isolated ampersand)*:

```
preg_match_all('~[^&]+(?:&&[^&]*)*|(?:&&[^&]*)+~', $uri, $result);
```

with `preg_split` *(check forward and backward with lookarounds)*:

```
$result = preg_split('~(?<!&)(?:&&)*+\K&(?!&)~', $uri);
```

or *(force the pattern to fail when there's "&&")*:

```
$result = preg_split('~&(?:&(*SKIP)(*F))?~', $uri);
```

without regex *(translate "&&" to another character and explode)*:

```
$result = explode('&', strtr($uri, ['%'=>'%%', '&&'=>'%']));
$result = array_map(function($i) { return strtr($i, ['%%'=>'%', '%'=>'&&']); }, $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another preg split:

```
preg_split("/(?<!&)&(?!&)/",$uri)
```

(Grab an ampersand not followed by or preceded by an ampersand)

Comment: Of the many options that work, this is the most legible and performant on most systems. That said, I do wonder if `parse_str()` isn't the better option for the ultimate end-goal. IOW: I'd love to back up and see the big picture goal instead of the specific question.

Comment: `parse_str` will biff on this particular case because it does split on each ampersand, so `query2=A`, then you get Empty key=Empty value (because there is exactly nothing between the 2 consecutive ampersands).

Comment: Also, I agree (at least imho) that my solution is the most legible, but what makes it more performant than the other suggestions?

Comment: Well it depends on the target string, of course, but some quick benchmarks show that it's magnitudes faster than the non-regex solution, nearly 2x as fast as `preg_match_all()`, and fractions faster than the two `preg_split()` solutions offered by Casimir. Essentially the `preg_split()` methods are a wash performance-wise, in which case I much prefer a direct, non-clever approach.